# How to get HTML5 to play a stream from Shoutcast

Tags: html, stream, shoutcast

Currently I am using a flash player to play my shoutcast stream. I would like people on mobile devices to be able to listen as well, and it seems HTML5 is the way to go.  How would I go about getting this shoutcast stream "stardust.wavestreamer.com:3353" working in HTML5?

I tried using

but that does not seem to be compatible with shoutcast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you connect to a SHOUTcast server with a web browser, it will detect your browser because it has `Mozilla` in the `User-Agent` header, and send you to the admin page for the stream anyway.  You can test this yourself by simply going to http://stardust.wavestreamer.com:3353/.

Fortunately, SHOUTcast servers provide a way to force the loading of the stream.  Just add a semicolon `;` to the end of the URL.

```
http://stardust.wavestreamer.com:3353/;
```

Internally in the SHOUTcast server, it will now see your `User-Agent` string as `MPEG OVERRIDE`, which no longer contains `Mozilla`, so you get the actual media stream.

Comment: Ok, so I am assuming you mean this line of code "    <audio src="http://stardust.wavestreamer.com:3353/" controls>"

I have tried this, and I cannot get the player to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: @StanPrice, Yes, your line of code is wrong.  The semicolon needs to be within the quotes.  That, and you should include the protocol.  `<audio src="http://stardust.wavestreamer.com:3353/;" />`

Comment: I feel so stupid...  You literally just changed my business in a big way. Thank you.

Comment: @Brad Is there a way to use this semicolon shortcut and play my stream with `?sid=2`? I can only get `?sid=1` to play.

Comment: @Mischa Yes, for SHOUTcast v2 servers, you can use http://stardust.wavestreamer.com:3353/;?sid=2

Comment: If I do that it plays `sid=1`. Everything after the semicolon seems to be ignored.