# Play an audio url using font awesome icon

Tags: html, button

I need some help to make my button to play music when I push it and not to pop up to another page.

I'm using this code

```html
<head>
  <title>Font Awesome Icons</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <center>
    <a href="http://radio.melodiapatras.gr/listen/melodia.htm" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
      <i class="fa fa-play-circle" style="font-size:150px;color:#1676cf"></i>
    </a>
  </center>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need javascript for it. Please run and check the code snippets for the function you need.

```css
button {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
}

button:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Font Awesome Icons</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <center>
    <button onclick=playMelodia()>
      <i class="fa fa-play-circle" style="font-size:150px;color:#1676cf"></i>
    </button>
    <audio id="melodia" controls="" style="display: none"><source src="http://i.streams.ovh:9523/stream.mp3" type="audio/mp3">Your browser does not support the audio element.</audio>

  </center>
  <script>
    function playMelodia() {
      document.getElementById("melodia").play();
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm using visual composer and I'm putting my code on html5. I don't know if there is a way to use JavaScript on visual composer.

Comment: @DionisisStefanopoulos I have updated the script to be written inside the body.

Comment: The only problem is that it has square around of the fa-circle. Maybe I'm doing something wrong

Comment: I putted <style> for the button into html and the square gone. But now on my site when I click it doesn't start the audio. Is there any way to do it? Maybe with hover?

Comment: Is it because of the audio source also no sound? U may check the source from the link you started above

Comment: Well after many changes and updates on the code I found out that it is a browser problem... On my phone plays correctly but on my pc doesn't. Is there a way to overcome this problem?

Comment: Is it your browser does not support the mp3? You may take out the "display: none" from the audio tag and load from your browser again to check.

Comment: To make simple I'm trying to get HTML5 to play a stream from Shoutcast http://i.streams.ovh:9523. I tried to use semicolon as I found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16871553/how-to-get-html5-to-play-a-stream-from-shoutcast but chrome keeps not playing my stream. I took out the display and the play button does nothing.

Comment: When I run the code as you posted abode it plays fine. When I post it on my site or w3schools it does nothing. I don't undersand it at all

Comment: Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_default' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure element 'http://i.streams.ovh:9523/stream.mp3'. This request was automatically upgraded to HTTPS, For more information see https://blog.chromium.org/2019/10/no-more-mixed-messages-about-https.html

Comment: The above comment is the console log from the chrome devtool when load from w3schools. You may check from your site and see if got similar error or warning.

Comment: So in conclusion, you think that the main problem is that my audio is not with ssl so google chrome on some sites it stops it from starting playing?

Comment: Yes. If your site is with SSL, your audio also must be from SSL. google chrome browser can't have mixed content from the secure site with the insecure element.

Comment: Ok. I will try to change it. Thanks a lot

Comment: Np. Glad to help.